# pass correctly script.sh $@ wrapped around single quotes

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, script

I have to execute scripts inside a docker container, example

```
composer install
```

or

```
bin/another-script another-script-arg-1 another-script-arg-2
```

in order to execute this command inside the container I have to execute something like (using docker-compose)

```
sudo docker-compose exec container-name sh -c 'bin/another-script another-script-arg-1 another-script-arg-2'
```

I want write a simple script that allow me save some typos and extra strokes for running just variances of the previous command, so I wrote an script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo docker-composer exec container-name sh -c "'bin/another-script $@'"
```

So I can execute outside, just

```
bin/another-script another-script-arg-1 another-script-arg-2
```

but doesnt work, just tellme something like 'bin/another-script' not found (inside container). I know this happens when the single quotes are not passed around the -c '' part. I have tried different stuff

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo docker-composer exec container-name sh -c \'bin/another-script $@\'
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo docker-composer exec container-name sh -c "'bin/another-script $@'"
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo docker-composer exec container-name sh -c "'"bin/another-script "$@""'"
```

**Edit**: the internal path of the script `bin/another-script` is not a problem because container move to the working dir, any case I've tested with the absolute path getting the same result `/app/bin/another-script`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo docker-composer exec container-name sh -c "'/app/bin/another-script $@'"
```

but nothing works, any advice?

Comment: The path is not a problem I can pass the absolute path and have the same result

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of trial and error. I found a way that worked I dont know if it's the best or correct way

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

container_cmd="bin/another-script $@"
sudo docker-composer exec container-name sh -c "$container_cmd"
```

I'd like to know why single quotes are not necessary